# How to use a Python keyword as an argument name for argparse?

Tags: python, argparse, keyword

`lambda` has a keyword function in Python:

```
f = lambda x: x**2 + 2*x - 5
```

What if I want to use it as a variable name? Is there an escape sequence or another way?

You may ask why I don't use another name. This is because I'd like to use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html):

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Calculate something with a quantity commonly called lambda.")
parser.add_argument("-l","--lambda",help="Defines the quantity called lambda", type=float)
args = parser.parse_args()

print args.lambda # syntax error!
```

Script called with `--help` option gives:

```
...
optional arguments
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -l LAMBDA, --lambda LAMBDA
                        Defines the quantity called lambda
```

Because of that, I would like to stay with `lambda` as the variable name. Solutions may be `argparse`-related as well.

Comment: Name it `Lambda` instead of `lambda`?

Comment: ...or name it `_lambda` or `lambda_`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use dynamic attribute access to access that specific attribute still:

```
print getattr(args, 'lambda')
```

Better still, tell `argparse` to use a different attribute name:

```
parser.add_argument("-l", "--lambda",
    help="Defines the quantity called lambda",
    type=float, dest='lambda_', metavar='LAMBDA')
```

Here the [`dest` argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#dest) tells `argparse` to use `lambda_` as the attribute name:

```
print args.lambda_
```

The help text still will show the argument as `--lambda`, of course; I set `metavar` explicitly as it otherwise would use `dest` in uppercase (so with the underscore):

```
>>> import argparse
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser("Calculate something with a quantity commonly called lambda.")
>>> parser.add_argument("-l", "--lambda",
...     help="Defines the quantity called lambda",
...     type=float, dest='lambda_', metavar='LAMBDA')
_StoreAction(option_strings=['-l', '--lambda'], dest='lambda_', nargs=None, const=None, default=None, type=<type 'float'>, choices=None, help='Defines the quantity called lambda', metavar='LAMBDA')
>>> parser.print_help()
usage: Calculate something with a quantity commonly called lambda.
       [-h] [-l LAMBDA]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -l LAMBDA, --lambda LAMBDA
                        Defines the quantity called lambda
>>> args = parser.parse_args(['--lambda', '4.2'])
>>> args.lambda_
4.2
```

Comment: `dest` solution does not work for positional arguments.

Comment: @unndreay: that's because for positional arguments the name *is* the `dest` parameter. Use `metavar` to provide a string to use in the help text there. `parser.add_argument('lambda_', metavar='lambda')`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't want to complain. Just noted.

Comment: I didn't take it as complaining. :-)

Answer (score 4):

There is an argparse-specific way of dealing with this. From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.Namespace):

> If you prefer to have dict-like view of the attributes, you can use
>   the standard Python idiom, `vars()`.

Therefore, you should be able to write:

```
print vars(args)["lambda"]  # No keyword used, no syntax error.
```

Answer (score 2):

`argparse` provides destination functionality for arguments if the long option name is not the desired attribute name for the argument.

For instance:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("--lambda", dest="function")

args = parser.parse_args()

print(args.function)
```