# Argparse and "in" option

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have what I think is a trivial issue, but was not able to find the reply.

I have a very simple argparse script:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--in', help='Input folder', default='../../in')
parser.add_argument('--out', help='Output folder', default='../../out')
args = parser.parse_args()
print(f'From {args.in} to {args.out}')
```

This results in an error:

```
  File "[...]\__main__.py", line 16
    (args.in)
          ^^
SyntaxError: f-string: invalid syntax
```

The issue, however, is only with the `in` parameter; if I remove it from the f-string the `out` parameter is printed successfully.

If I try to print the `args` variable I get

```
Namespace(in='../../in', out='../../out')
```

which means that the `in` parameter is read. I assume the `.in` way is reserved, but then... how do I access it?

If it is useful, I'm using Python 3.10.4 on Windows

Comment: `in` happens to be a keyword in python. That can easily break your code

Comment: `getattr(args, 'in')` should work.  Or `vars(args)['in']`

Comment: To use the `args.name` syntax, `name` has to be a valid attribute name, or equivalently, a valid variable name.  `argparse` uses `setattr` to set values in `args`, so the `dest` can be anything, even if it isn't a valid variable name.  While `getattr` can get around this, you rarely, if ever, have to use a invalid `dest`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot - [Why can't attribute names be Python keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746838/why-cant-attribute-names-be-python-keywords)

But, at the parsing level, you can specify `dest` argument, which will change the name that is assigned to the command line argument in Python.

```
parser.add_argument('--in', dest = "_in", help='Input folder', default='../../in')

print(f'From {args._in} to {args.out}')
```

This way you can still start the program with `--in ... --out ...` arguments without breaking the code.

Comment: Thank you; after the first comments I searched for "reserved keywords" instead of just "in", and found [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25118520/pythons-argparse-how-to-use-keyword-as-arguments-name) with the dest solution, and I confirm this works as expected. Thank you for the quick reply